# Why do I have to assign this node to a variable in my stylesheet?

Tags: xslt

I'm working on an XSLT stylesheet.  I have a a node (node A) with a bunch of children, and I'm looping through another node's (node B) children.  I'm trying to do something each time a child of node B is also a child of node A, so I have this code:

```
<xsl:if test="$prodbins/bin[./text()=/root/Line[1]/Element[6]/text()]">
```

But that doesn't work (the test fails; the expression returns false) even though the left and right side of the expression, when evaluated separately, are equal.

But when I do this:

```
<xsl:variable name="curbin" select="/root/Line[1]/Element[6]/text()"/>
<xsl:if test="$prodbins/bin[./text()=$curbin]">
```

The expression evaluates to true.  Why do I have to use the $curbin variable to get the result I'm expecting?

Comment: Can you try `<xsl:if test="$prodbins/bin[./text()=current()/root/Line[1]/Element[6]/text()]">` (notice current() function) - I don't remember if it works if you query a variable. The reason why it does not work is that because you query a variable `/` looks up the root node of the content of the variable and not the source document you are transforming. `current()` should return the context element for the template you are in if I remember correctly.

Comment: That does work.  Let me see if I understand you right - inside the `test` clause, the `/` is referring to the root of `$prodbins`, and not the root of the document?  Very interesting - I had no idea.  Want to post that as the answer?  Looks conclusive to me...

Comment: @Aerik, that doesn't make sense, `/` always selects the document to which the current context's node belongs. Are you handling more than one document?

Comment: Well, sort of:  `$prodbins` is coming from my stylesheet by way of doing  this `<xsl:variable name="prodbins" select="document('')//prodbindefs"/>` , so in a way I am dealing with two documents, since I'm treating the stylesheet as a document.  I'm getting the `$prodbins` variable that way because otherwise it wasn't recognized as a node-set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try `<xsl:if test="$prodbins/bin[./text()=current()/root/Line[1]/Element[6]/text()]">` (notice current() function). The reason why it does not work in your original expression is that because you query a variable and `/` looks up the root node of the content of the variable and not the source document you are transforming. current() should return the context element for the template you are in.

Answer (score 1):

**My guess is that `$prodbins/bin` is a node(-set) belonging to a different document than the document that contains the nodes that are being compared to**.

In the expression:

```
   $prodbins/bin[./text()=/root/Line[1]/Element[6]/text()]
```

the subexpression

```
   /root/Line[1]/Element[6]/text()
```

selects from the *same* document as the one that is the document from which the `$prodbins/bin` nodes are selected.

**One way to specify successfully the wanted comparisson is**:

```
<xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="/"/>

<xsl:if test="$prodbins/bin[./text()=$vDoc/root/Line[1]/Element[6]/text()]">
```